# C++ fstream getline parameters

Tags: c++, fstream

I am new to C++ and I want to ask a question about how to find a line in a file using fstream.
I only found this and would someone explain to me what these parameters mean?

file.getline（char *,int sz）；

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean [std::basic_stream::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline), you provide a pointer to character array and the size of that array. You have to create the array somewhere by yourself. If some line is longer than `sz - 1`, only part of it with length `sz - 1` will be read.

If you don't know the maximum length of lines in the input file, it's better to use [std::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), for example like this:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(file, line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

The first variable:

> Pointer to an array of characters where extracted characters are stored as a c-string.

The second variable:

> Maximum number of characters to write to s (including the terminating null character).
>   If the function stops reading because this limit is reached without finding the delimiting character, the failbit internal flag is set.
>   streamsize is a signed integral type.